# Customizable assembler/debugger/machine simulator

Tags: debugging, simulator, assembly

I'm looking for an integrated assembler/debugger/machine simulator with a fully customizable assembly language for teaching purposes. I'd also settle for some nice looking simulator with source code so I could adapt it to my needs. Can't seem to google anything useful. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[SPIM](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~larus/spim.html) is fairly good and free. Not sure about the customizable part though.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you [OVPsim](http://www.ovpworld.org/), it's free for non-commercial use and have very neat API, so you can create your own processor families or even platforms.
You can see sources for different platform emulation [here](http://code.google.com/p/ovplib/).  And find a help on processor developing [here](http://www.ovpworld.org/forum/login.php?redirect=viewforum.php&f=7&start=0).

Comment: Ah. I was hoping for a more integrated solution, but this one seems interesting. AFAIU, OVPSim requires an external tool (assembler/compiler) to produce application binaries for it? BTW, is there a macro assembler (or C cross-compiler) that could *easily* be extended to support new CPU architecture? ;)

Comment: Hm... I think it would far more better to you, to write machine command interpreter and don't bother with emulation, etc. For example MIX-machine: http://search.cpan.org/~litchie/Hardware-Simulator-MIX-0.5/lib/Hardware/Simulator/MIX.pm